# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1

I'm running `gradle signingReport --stacktrace`

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'danits'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The settings in **Android-Studio** need to be using **Java 17**:

Using **Linux** or **Windows**:

Menu: `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`

[image]

Using **macOS**:

`Preferences` -> `Build`, `Execution`, `Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`

---

If you don't have Java 17 installed on Windows: https://javacodepoint.com/jdk-17-installation-on-windows-10-step-by-step/

---

Comment: I just started a new project and am met with this error.
Is there any way to make it so new projects default to settings that work?

Comment: It seems impossible to change the default jdk (embedded jdk), In the File menu there is an option "New Projects Setup", but you don't have an option for default jdk.

Answer (score 84):

My solution:

**On macOS**

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

**On Windows**

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Select: **JDK 17** or **JDK 11**

And **Sync Gradle** again

[image]

Comment: using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Gradle JDK no longer is available

Answer (score 6):

If you are using command line `gradlew` or `gradle`:

**Using Linux**.
Set environment variable to java version 17

`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/my/jdk/1.17`

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

**Using Windows**.

Set environment variable to Java version 17
Create a JAVA_HOME with the path to your java 17
[image]
[image]
[image]

Or using command line:
`setx JAVA_HOME "path to java17"`

To add a system-wide environment variable, open the Command Prompt as administrator and use:
`setx JAVA_HOME "path to java17" /M`

Comment: I needed to do this to get a VS Code extension to work with it.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem wasn't from Gradle JDK
I just changed the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip` and it worked fine!

Gradle wrapper exists in this directory `/gradle/wrapper`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing the **distributionUrl** version to latest distribution one helped me.

***distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip***

path to the **distributionUrl** > gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just remove the

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and it work's for me, maybe it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

1. I set AGP 8.2.0
2. I set gradle version.
3. The only cause was I set default JDK for Android Studio was JAVA_1_8, but for gradle 8.+ we need to setup at lease JAVA_17. (Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK -> JDK 17)

If you use **Visual Studio**:

/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file edit:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip`

then, edit /app/build.gradle file:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'`

If you use **Android Studio**:
Setting:
[image]

Project Structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me its working after java version upgrade to 17 from 8
path to upgrade java version is
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

[image: image of android studio path for java version change]