# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.

[i change gradle-wrapper & build.gradle and still the same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyqtb.png)

Comment: question sounds familiar. can you check if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315325/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle8-0-1